# Setting up ROS Melodic with C

Tags: c, ros

I am trying to set up the dependencies for building packages for C ;however, the ROS website only gives the command for python

```
sudo apt install python-rosinstall python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool build-essential
```

Is there anyway I can run a similar command for C the project I'm trying to create is dependent on me having ros.

The website I took the commands are from is wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

The ubuntu version I am using is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Codename: bionic.

I am running these commands on NVIDIAs AGX XAVIER with an armv8-64 bit processor. https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-agx-xavier-developer-kit

If there is any additional information you need to help me please let me know. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

ROS should be able to work with Python and C++. For the former you need to include dependency on the rospy package and for the latter, roscpp.